# Troubles with specializing the function

Tags: c++, templates

I have to specialize the function, but with less parameters.

This is the original function:

```
template<typename T>
bool isAfter(const T &x, const T &y) {
    if (x < y) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And this is my try to specializing, but I get errors

```
template<> inline bool Templates::isAfter(std::vector<string> &vec) {

  for(int i=0; i<vec.size()-1; i++) {
    if(vec[i+1].size() < vec[i].size()) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Also the specialize definition is after class definition.

Comment: This is no specialization, just overload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having

> ```
>  template<typename T>
>  bool isAfter(const T &x, const T &y) {
>    if (x < y) {
>        return true;
>    }
>    return false;
>  }
> ```

a specialization can be

```
template<>
bool isAfter(const std::vector<std::string> &vec1, const std::vector<std::string> &vec2) { 
   return vec1.size() < vec2.size();
}
```

because that follows the signature with *T* being `std::vector<std::string>`

But in your case there is only *one* argument so you do not specialize, you define a function having the same name (overloading), remove `template<>`

P.S.

```
bool isAfter(std::vector<string> &vec) {
  for(int i=0; i<vec.size()-1; i++) {
    if(vec[i+1].size() < vec[i].size()) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
bool isAfter(std::vector<string> &vec) {
  if (vec.size() > 1)
    return (vec[1].size() >= vec[0].size());
  /* missing return value */
}
```

perhaps you wanted

```
bool isAfter(std::vector<string> &vec) {
  for(int i=0; i<vec.size()-1; i++) {
    if(vec[i+1].size() < vec[i].size()) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you. I was also thinking this must be overloading and not specializing. But in instructions of task is written that original function has two parameters, and specialized function must have only vector without second argument, so there must be mistake made by our professor, writing instructions. 

Thank you anyway, to share your opinion.